# CakePHP-2.0: How can i redirect to home page when someone hits url http://site/controller/unknownaction in CakePHP-2.0?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

```
http://site/users/abcd
```

Here is the error=>

```
Error: The action abcd is not defined in controller UsersController

Error: Create UsersController::abcd() in file: app/Controller/UsersController.php.
```

I want to catch this error, and redirect to home/index.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry I read over the Cake **2.0**

Take a look at this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#using-appcontroller-apperror

---

Try the manual [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/154/Error-Handling)

```
class AppError extends ErrorHandler {
    function missingAction($parameters) {
        $this->controller->redirect('/');
    }
}
```

[Error.php](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/error.php) contains functions that handle cakePHP errors, you just override them

Comment: No, this won't work, missingAction is for cakephp-1.3.10. and that link you gave is for cakephp-2.0 development.

Answer (score 2):

You could take the 404 page template and add a HTML redirect there.
The file to modify would be:
    app/views/errors/missing_controller.ctp

UPDATE:
My bad, if it's missing an action then update:
    app/views/errors/missing_action.ctp

Comment: It's not missing controller, it's missing action.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I've added the missing_action file in the answer.